# Dropdown Dinamico e Impressão de Valores?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um painel BI, e nele estou buscando todas as **REDES** e colocando dentro de um dropdown, até aí tudo certo

Segue código:

```
<div class="row wow fadeInRight">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <form action="#">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="drops-labels"><b id="centraliza-txt">REDE</b></label>
                                        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="ESCOLHA A REDE">
                                            <?php
                                                echo "<select class='form-control input-sm' name='redes' id='rede'>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>--Selecione--</option>";
                                                while($dadosRedes = mysql_fetch_array($buscarDadosSuperv)) {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$dadosRedes['Rede']."'>".$dadosRedes['Rede']."</option>";
                                                    }
                                                echo "</select>";
                                            ?>
                                        </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Porém, tenho outro dropdown que estou querendo que seja preenchido a partir de um `select` no meu banco de dados, trazendo todas as **LOJAS** desta respectiva **REDE**.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
                            <form action="#">
                                <div class="form-group" id="load_lojas">
                                    <label id="drops-labels"><b id="centraliza-txt">LOJA</b></label>
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="ESCOLHA A LOJA">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="loja" id="loja">
                                            <option value="0">--Selecione--</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Tentei fazer com Ajax e Jquery e nada.

E após isso, quero preencher os valores encontrados em uma tabela fazendo um `select` na minha tabela, filtrando por **REDE** e **LOJA**.

Comment: Depois [leia isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Dá uma conferida neste artigo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857287/how-to-make-a-cascading-drop-down-list-in-php-using-jquery ali tem o esquema.

Comment: Ainda não consegui @NIZZOLA, ajuda?